Collecting varying element indices from a tensor across multiple dimensions
Assume I got the following tensor:
arr = torch.randint(0, 9, (100, 50, 3))

What I want to achieve is collecting, for example, 2 elements of that tensor, let's start with collecting the 6th and 56th one:
indices = torch.tensor([5, 55])
partial_arr = arr[indices]

This gives me an array of  shape
torch.Size([2, 50, 3])

Now, let's assume that from the first element, I want to collect the elements 5 through 10
first_result = partial_arr[0, 5:10]

and from the second element, the elements from 10 to 15:
second_result = partial_arr[1, 10:15]

Since I want everything in one tensor, I can do:
final_result = torch.cat([first_result, second_result])

How can I achieve the final result only with one operation on the first tensor: arr = torch.randint(0, 9, (100, 50, 3)) ?

do all slices have the same number of elements (here 5)?

Yes, that is correct. I always want the same range (here 5) from the first dimension

Assuming the number of sliced elements remains constant across rows, you can create an arrangement tensor and shift it by the per-row starting index:
>>> idx = torch.tensor([5,10])
>>> idx_ = torch.arange(5,)[None]+idx[:,None]
tensor([[ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])

Then expand idx_ such that it has the same last dimension size as partial_arr:
>>> idx_ = idx_[...,None].expand(-1,-1,partial_arr.size(-1)) 
# shaped torch.Size([2, 5, 3])

Finally, gather the values using torch.gather:
>>> partial_arr.gather(1,idx_).shape
tensor([[[8, 3, 1],
         [2, 4, 6],
         [4, 4, 5],
         [2, 8, 6],
         [3, 7, 0]],

        [[3, 6, 7],
         [5, 7, 4],
         [1, 5, 4],
         [4, 5, 3],
         [7, 1, 2]]])

